# How to click on data-link of div in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing

Consider the following code:

```
<div class="results">

<div class="search-results" data-link="some url1">result1</div>
<div class="search-results" data-link="some url2">result2</div>
<div class="search-results" data-link="some url3">result3</div>
<div class="search-results" data-link="some url4">result4</div>


</div>
```

Above is a search box in which as we type text it shows some results in the dropdown (ajax call).

The results (as shown in the above code) are links but they are without `<a>`

How to click on one of these results (say the first result) as they are without `<a>`?

Comment: what happens when you click the div element say //div[@data-link="some url4"]

Comment: @PDHide:nothing

Comment: could you add the screen shot

Comment: @PDHide:Not allowed

Comment: @PDHide: Sorry //div[@data-link="some url4"] .click() is working.

Comment: Great!! . Could you accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
//div[@data-link="some url4"].click()
```

**If that doesn't work then:**

data-link is a jquery attribute , unless we can see the page-source its hard to tell what to do . One trick is to check  in script and see click action on what element navidates to the link:

IT will look something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(".urllink").click(function (e) {

        var link = $(this).data("data-link");
        blabla

    });

</script>
```

and try to initiate click on that specific element